# Laravel 5.1 working with redis

Tags: php, node.js, redis, laravel-5

Here is my Routes.php

```
Route::get('hello1',function(){
    Redis::publish('test-channel', json_encode(['foo' => 'bar']));
});
```

here is my app.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();


app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


redis.subscribe('test-channel', function () {
    console.log('Redis: test-channel subscribed');
});

redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    console.log('Redis: Message on ' + channel + ' received!');
    console.log(message);
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel, message.payload)
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});


http.listen(6379, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:6379');
});
```

my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Socket.IO</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="messages">
    <li>Hardcoded Message</li>
</ul>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io();
    socket.on("test-channel", function(message) {
        console.log(message);
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(message));
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

now whenever is run php artisan redis:subscribe or hello1 route i am getting error like,

> ConnectionException in AbstractConnection.php line 146: Error while
>   reading line from the server. [tcp://localhost:6379]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis by default is listening on port 6379 and you have set your http server to listen on the same port. This won't work, don't you get an error when trying to run your node app? If you don't get an error, redis most probably is not running at all or listening on another port.

If your redis instance is listening on another port, laravel will try to connect to redis on port 6379 and will hit on the node server and therefor, can't connect to redis as there is no redis but a node http server listening on this port.

If your redis instance is listening on another port and you have changed this in your laravel config, you would have to change the way you are connecting ioredis to redis by passing the port:

For example

```
var redis = new Redis(6380)
```

See the [github page](https://github.com/luin/ioredis) for further details on connecting ioredis to redis.

As a conclusion, make sure that

1. Redis is running
2. Your http server is listening on another port than redis is
3. Your connection settings for redis in your config/database.php and config/broadcast.php (laravel) and for node in your server.js file are correct

Note that **not** the http server is connecting to redis, ioredis is.

Comment: Thanks Michael Sir .
Installing redis server and starting through dos mode makes everything fine. But whenever i am trying to start the redis server via node js all the time i get error is events.js:85 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event ^
Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - read ECONNRESET at RedisClient.on_error I couldnt understand whyy

Comment: You are welcome! Redis needs to run before you start the connection from node. Node won't start it with the code you have. There's a good explanation on setting up redis the right way here

Comment: But i am afraid how do i these on real live server now it was easy for me since i was on windows going to the CLI mode and opening the port for the redis server :) Anyway thank you michael you saved my time a lot 1000 thanks to you sir